# Margin on iFrame Tag

Tags: html, iframe, margin

I have an iFrame tag that loads a scrolling picture banner, and when it loads it has a new html and body tag inside a #document. Everything loads ok, but the problem is that is has an auto 8px margin. I have set every property I can think of to 0px but nothing affects it. I have tried the ideas on the posts about similar issues, but nothing has worked.

```
<div id="header">

    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="menuItem"> <a href="home.html">Home</a>  </li>
        <li class="menuItem"> <a href="music.html">Music</a>  </li>
        <li class="menuItem">  <a href="services.=html">Services</a>  </li>
        <li class="menuItem">  <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>  </li>
        <li class="menuItem">  <a href="bio.html">Bio</a>  </li>
    </ul>

<iframe src="standard.html" id="bannerObj" scrolling="no" margin="0"></iframe>
```

Here is the full code on jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/35rf6ga6/

Comment: Can you add the code for standard.html, please?

Comment: just added it.... pasted in the html window

Comment: Thanks @Taylor Barton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iframe has a border by default.
Try putting a `border="0"` attribute on your iframe element or add `border: none;` in CSS.

Comment: Not quite... Thanks for pointing that out, because I did have a border, but its the <body> inside the iFrame that is having the problem. When I inspect element, everything lines up until I look at that nested<body> tag

Comment: Make sure you have an `html` and `body` tag in your `standard.html` markup. I understand the browser will add them when you omit them but you won't be able to change the margin on the body tag. 
I'm looking at your update at https://jsfiddle.net/35rf6ga6/2/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so in your iFrame, add `frameBorder="0"`. This will remove the border and show your iFrame.

Here is an example of what it should look like:

```
<iframe src="myUrlPathHere" id="bannerObj" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" margin="0"</iframe>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35rf6ga6/3/)

a few things i noticed:

You have an error printed in #000 (not visible because that's the background)

```
{"error": "Please use POST request"}
```

(That could just be because you are locally calling the script. Perhaps use a cdn such as cdnjs.com

And it doesn't seems to me like there is a margin... just a border...

Good Luck!

**EDIT:** here is a CDN for your slider from cdnjs.com

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jssor-slider/25.2.0/jssor.slider.min.js
```